# Lenovo E530 charging problem on Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

I have **Lenovo E530 laptop**. And sometimes I have charging problem. It doesnt want to charge over specified battery %. Sometimes its 17%, sometimes 50%, number is changing. Where should be a problem? Exists some special drivers for thinkpads on ubuntu? (In windows I solve this problem by installing power manager from lenovo, but I`m not sure if exists something for ubuntu or linux). What do u suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS update** was the right solution.